# While closing the browser tab in Selenium run, Pop-up alert not displayed, but pop-up is displayed when manually closing the browser tab

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenide

Our application has a popup alert built-in if user closes the browser tab. It works when I manually close the Chrome browser tab, but when I use Selenium methods like `driver.close()` or `quit()`, or `Keys(COMMAND + w)` it doesn't throw any pop up - but directly closes the browser.

Is there anyway to display that prompt/popup/alert as it is normally thrown on manual run?

[image: Popup image]

I tried all possible ways to close the browser tab, and all those methods directly closing the browser tab without throwing the pop up.

I want the popup to be displayed before closing the browser tab, as it normally appears on manual execution.

Comment: driver.quit() will not work as that will shut down the browser and dispose of the driver. 
 When using the driver.close() command the current tab/window will be closed.  If it's the last tab/window opened, it may also quit the driver (depends on the driver used).  It's possible that this behavior is causing your issue.  To avoid that, make sure there is more than one window/tab open in the browser.  Call, executeScript("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');");  before calling driver.close()...  (you may also want to use expected condition of numberOfWindowsToBe...)

Comment: since this will be triggered onbeforeunload, another alternative is just to send driver .back(), or .refresh() commands.